# How to sort with specific order in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following sample table and one status field.

```
Name | status
-------------
Ab   | 2
Xy   | 0
Pq   | 3
Rs   | 1
```

I would like to execute query and would like to sort in this way.

```
Name | status
-------------
Rs   | 1
Ab   | 2
Pq   | 3
Xy   | 0
```

Is it possible in MySql query?

**Note : Here `status` field is `ENUM`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also try

```
order by find_in_set(`status`, '1,2,3,0');
```

Comment: Can it perform on `ENUM` field type?

Comment: It I specify like `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, "'1','2','3','0'")` then it's not working but only works like `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status, "1,2,3,0")`

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by the `status` but put `0` at the end by the first order condition.

In MySQL you can do (since boolean results are evaluated to `1` and `0`)

```
select * from your_table
order by status = 0,
         status
```

in other DB engines you can use

```
select * from your_table
order by case when status <> 0 then 1 else 2 end,
         status
```

Comment: Yeeepeee. It's working but now How I could specify '3' status in case when?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The case specifies that `0` comes last. I used `1` and `2` to indicate a sort order. That could have been `6` and `9`. It does not matter.

Comment: So do you mean that by above case if there are more value for status like 1,2,3,4,5,6 all will be displayed in order (1,2,3,4,5,6) and 0 will be display at last?

Answer (score 1):

**I got Four solutions for this:-**

> SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY FIELD(status,3,0);
>
> SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY  find_in_set(`status`, '1,2,3,0');
>
> SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY status = 0,status;
>
> SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY CASE WHEN status <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
>   status;

Comment: What does this? `SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY FIELD(status,3,0);`

Comment: SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY FIELD(status,1,2,3,0);

Comment: http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/mysql-ordering-results-by-specific-field-values/

Comment: @NullPointer when you want to sort the results in a specific order which cannot be done using the ASC or DSC. FIELD() of MySQL ORDER BY clause can be used to sort the results in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MySQL query to sort the data in ASC or DESC order

```
  SELECT column_name(s)
  FROM table_name
  ORDER BY column_name(s) ASC|DESC
```